# Approximation for mean(abs(fft(vector)))?

Tags: matlab, fft, approximation

Some MatLab code I'm trying to simplify goes through the effort of finding FFT, only to take the absolute value, and then the mean:

```
> vector = [0 -1 -2 -1 0 +1 +2 +1];
> mean(abs(fft(vector)))
ans = 2
```

All these coefficients are built up, then chopped back down to a single value. The platform I'm working on is really limited, and if I can get by without using FFT, all the better. Is there a way to approximate these operations without FFT?

Can assume `vector` will be at most 64 values in length.

Comment: What exactly is this value supposed to represent?

Comment: What's wrong with doing it like this? Is it a performance bottleneck?

Comment: (at) david - don't know, there are no comments. (at) eitan - yes, big time. Platform has no native floating point.

Comment: It looks like some kind of “average frequency” of the input vector (mean of the one-sided spectrum). Are there any properties of the input vector that you could exploit to estimate or look up the answer? For example, is the input vector always one of a handful of values? Is the input signal bandlimited? Is it always integers? Over what range?

Comment: This looks like the computation of a crude approximation to RMS, or sqrt(RMS).  Is there some reason why the actual RMS won't do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a just a very inefficient way of calculating the RMS value of the signal. See [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Plancherel_theorem_and_Parseval.27s_theorem). You can probably just simplify the expression to:

```
sqrt(mean(vector.*vector))
```

Comment: How did you infer the question is about RMS? I see neither "root" nor "square"...

Comment: This cant be correct. It could be (without the root) if mean(abs(fft(vector)).^2) is to be computed.

Comment: I think this might be good enough. If f(x) is the original formula, and g(x) is yours, then f(x) ~= 2*sqrt(pi)*g(x)

Comment: @PaulR Parseval's theorem is for mean(abs(fft(vector)).^2). There is no square in the original question

Answer (score 1):

If your vector is real and has zero average as in your example, you can take advantage of the fact that the two halves of the DFT are complex-conjugate (from basic signal processing) and save half the abs computations. Also, use `sum`, which is faster than `mean`:

```
fft_vector = fft(vector);
len = length(fft_vector)/2; 
sum(abs(fft_vector(1:len)))/len
```